# How to create SOQL query for Opportunity, Account and Contact?

Tags: soql

I want to write single Query to fetch opportunity, account and Account's Contact based on opportunity Id. It's like Child-> Parent -> Child relationship

```
Select id, Amount, CloseDate, Account.Name,(Select Contact.Name From
Account.Contacts) from Opportunity Where id=''
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't query "up then down". Instead, you can query from the Account.

```
SELECT Name...,
       (SELECT Name... FROM Contacts),
       (SELECT Name, Amount, CloseDate... FROM Opportunities WHERE Id = :oppId)
FROM Account
   WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId)
```